# Roslyn - CSharpCompilation

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am using the `CSharpCompilation` class to compile a `SyntaxTree` where the root is a class declaration. I pass to the constructor a `CSharpCompilationOptions` object which contains my using statements.

My understanding is that the syntax tree will be compiled using the context of any using statements I pass through. However when trying to access a class which is defined in one of the 'usings' I pass to the options object I get an error saying it doesn't exist in the current context.

I am clearly doing something wrong. Anybody know what the list of usings is for when passed to the `CSharpCompilationOptions` class?

This is the code:

```
public static void TestMethod()
    {
        string source = @"public class Test
{
    public static void TestMethod()
    {
        string str = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    }
}";
        SyntaxTree syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(source);

        List<string> usings = new List<string>()
        {
            "System.IO", "System"
        };
        List<MetadataFileReference> references = new List<MetadataFileReference>()
        {
            new MetadataFileReference(typeof(object).Assembly.Location),
        };   

        //adding the usings this way also produces the same error
        CompilationUnitSyntax root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)syntaxTree.GetRoot();
        root = root.AddUsings(usings.Select(u => SyntaxFactory.UsingDirective(SyntaxFactory.IdentifierName(u))).ToArray());
        syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.Create(root);

        CSharpCompilationOptions options = new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary, usings: usings);
        CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("output", new[] { syntaxTree }, references, options);

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(stream);

            if (result.Success)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you add a reference to the assembly?

Comment: Yes I did. If I create a syntax tree that contains the using statements it compiles fine.

Comment: Can you include the code that sets the option and compiles?

Comment: Yeah, this probably means you didn't specify any assemblies to reference -- the stuff you normally see under "References" in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: @KevinPilch-Bisson I have included the code. I am definitely adding a reference to the assembly so I don't think that is the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, it turns out that `CSharpCompilationOptions.Usings` is only ever examined in the compiler when compiling script files.  If you trace through the references, it ends up getting used [here](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Binder/BinderFactory.BinderFactoryVisitor.cs#841), inside an `if (inScript)` check.

We probably need to document that better.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've tried a different approach by updating the syntax tree and adding the 'usings' this way. I've edited the code to show my approach.

Comment: Forgot to add that this is producing the same error.

Comment: I can repro that not working.  Not sure why though. I'm following up with some people.

Comment: Is there any news on this?

Comment: Sorry, there hasn't been.  Can you file an issue on http://roslyn.codeplex.com so that we don't lose track of it?

Comment: @KevinPilch -- Your profile says that you have more recently been the "manager of the IDE team for Microsoft's Roslyn project".  Hopefully, you have managed to fix this issue...